# React: Custom hook keeps executing whenever I use moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

This is my custom hook and component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

const useMyHook = ({ foobar } = {}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const fetchStuff = useCallback(
    async ({ foobar }) => {
      try {
        console.log("TRY");
        setData([]);
        setCount(0);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
        setError(e);
      } finally {
        console.log("FINALLY");
        setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [setError, setCount, setData, setLoading]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("USE EFFECT");
    fetchStuff({ foobar });
  }, [fetchStuff, foobar]);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    count,
    data,
    refresh: fetchStuff
  };
};

export default function App() {
  console.log("RENDERING");

  // COMMENT THIS IN TO SEE BUG
  // const foobar = moment().valueOf();
  // const { loading, error, data, refresh } = useMyHook({ foobar });

  // COMMENT THIS OUT
  const { loading, error, data, refresh } = useMyHook({ foobar: 123 });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The hook keeps executing (leading to a stack overflow) whenever I use moment. However, I have verified that my moment call only returns an integer.

```
moment().subtract(1, 'month').valueOf()
> 1596480792170
```

If I replace `useMyHook({ foobar });` with a harcoded int like so: `useMyHook({ foobar: 123 });`
everything works fine. However, if I use moment, if you run my sandbox link below and look into the console, it overflows.

What am I doing wrong?

Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-glade-elpyl

Comment: wouldn't the moment call return a new value every time its called? IIRC i think `moment()` will just return the current time which would be a new value everytime a render is called.

Comment: That makes sense. So I would have to set the default date from within the hook itself instead of passing it one that's dynamically generated from the component

Comment: You could just `useMemo` from the app as well. `useMemo(() => moment().subtract(1, 'month').valueOf(), [])`

Comment: Good call. I haven't ever used useMemo, it looks like a good place to place a default date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment will return the current time every time its called which will trigger the effect in `useMyHook` causing a re render, causing another moment call, ..., and an infinite loop. Simply cache the first moment call somewhere to solve this. Using state with a value factory is recommended, but memo would also work.

```
const [foobar, updateFoobar] = useState(() => moment().subtract(1, 'month').valueOf());
const foobar = useMemo(() => moment().subtract(1, 'month').valueOf(), []);
```